# Cannot execute binary error on an Intel Xeon Phi

Tags: c++, c, cluster-computing, icc, xeon-phi

I am having a C code that compiles and runs properly locally on my machine.
But when I am trying to compile with the icc and the -mmic flag and test it on Intel Xeon Phi, I am getting the following message:

***/cm/local/apps/sge/current/spool/node079/job_scripts/5438755: line 14: ./sequential.mic: cannot execute binary file***

I run all my tests in a cluster which uses SGE job submission system.

**My makefile contains these lines:**

```
sequential: Makefile
icc -mmic -o sequential.mic sequential.c
qsub sequential.job
```

***The job file for submitting the job is:***

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -l h_rt=00:10:00
#$ -j y
#$ -l fat,accel=XeoPhi
#$ -cwd

. /etc/bashrc

module load intel/compiler/64/13.3/2013.3.163

./sequential.mic
```

Notes:

- If i compile it with gcc and submit it to a regular node (XEON 5620)
  everything works as expected.
- Also, i tried the file command to examine to the mic executable and the output is : **sequential.mic: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped**

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code needs to run natively on the Intel Xeon Phi, the binary also need t be loaded on the machine ahead of execution.

Therefore, the simplest way to do that is with the following command which loads the binary and then executes.

**/usr/bin/micnativeloadex ./sequential.mic**